# Load pure javascript library from node_modules with ng build --configuration=<env>

Tags: javascript, angular, build

I have an Angular 7 app that use pure javascript files from the node_modules folder. All files are referenced correctly but when I run the next command:

```
ng serve -o

#or

ng build #without any advanced configuration
```

But when I run the build command:

```
ng build --configuration=pre
```

The output deployed app doesn't show any error but the library is not loaded and executed correctly.

Is there any available configuration to load that library from node_modules in order to use within our Angular 7 projects?

For sake of reference the library used is: mapbox-gl-draw-rectangle-mode

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the references to this libraries in angular.json file in the section "scripts" inside "build -> options" key as follow:

```
"build": {
    ...
    "options": {
        ...
        "scripts":[
           "{path to js file in node_modules or where is storage}"
        ]
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it without success, I had an unexpected token 'export' error.

Comment: Mmm, looks like the path is wrong. I put an example for better clarity:

"scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
]

Comment: Actually I add the dependency with:

    npm install -S mapbox-gl-draw-rectangle-mode

Within the code I reference with:

    import DrawRectangle from 'mapbox-gl-draw-rectangle-mode';

And within the angular.json file I reference as you told me:

    node_modules/mapbox-gl-draw-rectangle-mode/src/index.js

I tried both /src/ and /dist/ folders.

With ng-serve is successful but when you run with ng build --configuration=pre it doesn't show any error but the library is not working

Comment: Ok, What do you have inside pre configuration in angular.json?

Comment: Same as the production but with other environment path variables.

Comment: Have you tried with ng build --prod? I think may be has some reference error in some place. Inside the dist folder after you run ng build --configuration=pre this library exists in some place?

Comment: Yes, I run ng build --prod without success, and I have nothing related with that library when I run on production and pre-production environment.